# What is the advantage of using Hash code over HTTP Connection

Tags: security, hash

I wonder to know when we send a data over HTTP and hash our password, why does the attacker need the actual password and use Dictionary Attack? 
As long as the received hash code is compared with the Store hash Code, they can simply use Hash Code in their request and reach our site. 
If is it true so what is the advantage of Hashing ! and why just not to secure our and just encrypt it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really would send the hash for authentication, this actually offers no security advantage, since the hash in fact would become the new password. But usually it is done in another way: The client sends the password, the receiver hashes it and compares it to the stored hash. Of course You should encrypt this communication to protect against eavesdroppers. You store only hashed versions of passwords to make it more difficult to recover them if an attacker somehow gets access to your database.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different problems you're addressing, here.

The first, very normal problem you're addressing is how do I protect the passwords I'm storing server side to use for authentication.  First, you should read [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/39623).  Then pick SCrypt, BCrypt, or PBKDF2, determine the iteration count/work factor that takes the amount of time you expect to have available during peak load, use a cryptographically random salt of 8 to 16 bytes or so, and store the salt (plaintext), the iteration count/work factor (plaintext, so it can be increased trivially), and the resulting hash in the database/storage medium.

If you choose PBKDF2, note that 64-bit implementations of PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-384 and PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512 reduce the margin of advantage attackers with early 2014 vintage GPU's have over your presumably CPU based solution due to 64-bit operations being quite slow on these GPU's.

Also a note on PBKDF2 - for password hashing in particular, never choose an output size greater than the size of the native hash.  For SHA-512, that's 64 bytes, SHA-384 is 48 bytes, SHA-256 is 32 bytes, SHA-224 is 28 bytes, and SHA-1 is 20 bytes.

The second problem you're addressing is how do I protect the passwords in motion from the client to my server.  Normally, people simply rely on TLS for this.  However, if you like, you can use the same techniques client side as you do server side (above), and then when you get the password hash at the server, you STILL apply SCrypt/BCrypt/PBKDF2 just as if you'd received a plaintext password from the client!  Therefore, an attacker who gets a copy of your authentication database still can't log in via the normal application channels until they use the normal attack methods used against properly hashed passwords, since the hashes they have to send are not the same as the hashes in your database!

To answer the question in the title, the hash over HTTP doesn't really do much beyond requiring eavesdroppers doing work to figure out what the user typed in - they can still authenticate to your application with the hash.  Use HTTPS instead!

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is not a correct way to use hashed passwords, and does have the security flaw you refer to.

Typically the way this is done is to secure the communications channel (E.g. use HTTPS with a certificate signed by a recognized certificate authority) and send the password to the server.  The server then hashes the password and compares it against the hash of the correct password for that user.

Hashing the password on the server protects the site user from compromise of the web site itself (makes it harder for the attacker to take the database and get a list of passwords associated with usernames that they might be able to use on other sites.

It isn't strictly necessary to send the password to the server, but each alternative has trade-offs.  Alternatives include:

- CHAP - Requires the server store the plaintext password.
- Certificates - Fails the ease-of-use test (hard).

Comment: Using some kind of challenge response scheme seems one of the few (if not the only) legimate reasons not to hash stored passwords.